# How to change delimeter/seperator when exporting a Spark dataframe from Azure Databricks via display(dataframe) command?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I want to export a dataframe within DataBricks to CSV.
I am using the following code:

```
data= data_raw.copy()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

Then I am using the right click option to export the dataframe.
The data file contains `,` seperated values.
I want to change the delimiter from `,` to `;` but I don't know how.

Do you have any ideas?

data_raw contains two columns:
1 Number
2 Text

Example Data

| Number | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | This is a text, containing letters. It can contain multiple , |
| 2 | This a new text,it contains several letters |

Comment: @bint, can you please provide the sample data that variable `data_raw` holds?

Comment: @Chris thank's for your answer. It is working for the basic export. The challenge is that i want to change the delimeter before doing the export. The standard delimeter is a comma: , . I want to export the data with a semicolon: ;.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I want to export a basic pandas dataframe. This basic pandas dataframe is being created with pd.read_csv() command. Do you need any further information?

Comment: Please provide sample data stored inside `data_raw`.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham The dataframe data_raw is a pandas dataframe and contains two columns: 1. Column = Number 2. Column = text. Example data: 1, This a test, containing a test.

Comment: Understood. Please add sample data for that (say 2 sample rows to give an idea about how the data looks like)

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I have created a dataframe in the post above. Thanks for your great support so far!

Comment: @bint, how many rows are you dealing with here?

Comment: 6687 Rows up to 480.000 Rows but not more.

Comment: @bint You can just add`.option('delimiter',';')` to your csv output code

Comment: @Chris is it possible to combine command ".option('delimeter',';') with  spark.createDataFrame(data)? Should the command look like the following: spark.createDataFrame(data).option('delimeter',';') ?

Comment: The delimiter is for output, not for creation of a dataframe - if you're trying to use the export button w/a custom delimiter I'm not aware of a way